# HTTP Retrieval error Twilio

Tags: python, heroku, flask, twilio

I'm new to Twilio and I am trying to send and receive sms via python. Here is my code

```
import os
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from twilio import twiml
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


# put your own credentials here
ACCOUNT_SID = "..."
AUTH_TOKEN = "..."

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

def respond (recipient, twilio_account, body):

    message = client.messages.create(
        to=recipient,
        from_=twilio_account,
        body=body,
    )

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def receive_sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    body = request.form['Body']
    # print "Message received from {0} saying {1}".format(number, body)
    response_message = "Message received from {0} saying {1}".format(number, body)

    resp = twiml.Response()
    resp.message(response_message)
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

I keep getting a 11200 error everytime I text my Twilio number. What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This error [indicates that Twilio didn't receive a response from your code within 15 seconds](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200).

I don't see any reason your code would run slowly, but Twilio may not be able to access it at all. Have you taken any steps to let requests into your local network from the Internet?

One useful strategy is to use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) while you're still in development to tunnel traffic in from the outside world. After installing ngrok you [can run](https://ngrok.com/docs#expose)

```
ngrok http 5000
```

to tunnel traffic in to your localhost port 5000. Then configure Twilio to connect to the ngrok tunnel.

Comment: I understand ngrok is an alternative, but I don't see why this would be causing an errors

Comment: @JeremyFisher, somehow Twilio needs to be able to hit URLs in your application. ngrok is one easy way of letting this happen. There are others (e.g. you can use port forwarding, possibly in conjunction with a dynamic DNS tool in case you don't have a static IP address). Have you done anything like that?